# Make "Version Note" mandatory in frontend form

Tags: articles, front-end, component-configuration

I am using **Joomla 3.6.5**. On my site I allow registered Authors to **add articles**.

**"Version Note"** is one of the fields but it is optional.

I want to make it mandatory. I have enabled versioning for articles.

How can I make this field mandatory?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Terry says, the best way to do this (without editing or overriding the code) is probably to add some JavaScript to the page.

Based on the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10034643/1983389 the JavaScript code will probably look something like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $("#jform_version_note").attr('required','required');
});
```

You can add the JavaScript using a third party extension such as one of the following:

- [Easy Script](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/easyscript) plugin (free)
- [Flexi Custom Code](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/flexi-custom-code) module (free)
- [Add Custom Javascript](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/add-custom-javascript) module or plugin (free)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a Joomla setting that makes it required. You could add a plug in that fires a Javascript after page load, adding the required attribute to that element though. Could probably even add some jquery script to the head of your site that forces required.

Answer (score 1):

Although I accepted Neil's answer, I found an easier method to do this. But my method may not appeal to many since it requires changing XML files of default Joomla installation. Perhaps there's a way to write a custom XML to override the settings selectively in the default XML.

Article form settings are available in these files:

```
administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml (backend)
components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml (frontend)
```

To the `version_note` field, I added an extra attribute:

```
required="true"
```

Though not directly relevant to the question, I would like to add that only the form settings are in XML. Global article options themselves are stored in the `#_extensions` database table in `params` column for `name='com_content'`. For versioning, applicable fields are `save_history` and `history_limit`. In addition, every article can override the global options but versioning is one of those features for which article-level overriding is not possible.